# Check if round up or down?

Tags: java, math, addition, rounding

I'm handling with some numbers and I want to add to the rounded number a specific faktor.

Like:

if round down -> add 150
if round up -> add 100

Is there any possibility to check if the computer is rounding up or down?

Comment: Where is your number ? Show us some code .

Comment: Let me see if I get it: you are taking a float number (153.6) and trying to check if it's rounding to 153 or 154?

Comment: for example: I have a number -> int number = 33.  then I want to round -> usually it's 30. here I want to check if the computer is rounding down (it is) so add 100 -> 30 + 100 = 130 = number

but if number = 36, it will be rounded -> 40; it was rounded up so I want to add 150 instead of 100 (like at rounded down) -> 40+150=190

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can know if you rounded up or down like this

```
float roundedNbr = Math.round(originalNbr);

if(roundedNbr < originalNbr) {
    // We rounded down
} else if (roundedNbr > originalNbr) {
    // We rounded up
} else {
    // No rounding
}
```